# How to replace data of an array if some value match

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have this array's and I want to replace the data form the array1 with the data of array2 if there is some coincident, for example that replace from the array1 {"Dates":"05/25/2021","valor":"0"} the data of array2 {Dates: "05/25/2021", count: "20"} that match

```
array1 = [{Dates:"05/10/2021",count:"0"},{Dates:"05/11/2021",count:"0"},{Dates:"05/12/2021",count:"0"},{Dates:"05/13/2021",count:"0"},{Dates:"05/14/2021",count:"0"},{Dates:"05/15/2021",count:"0"},{Dates:"05/16/2021",count:"0"},{Dates:"05/17/2021",count:"0"},{Dates:"05/18/2021",count:"0"},{Dates:"05/19/2021",count:"0"},{Dates:"05/20/2021",count:"0"},{Dates:"05/21/2021",count:"0"},{Dates:"05/22/2021",count:"0"},{Dates:"05/23/2021",count:"0"},{Dates:"05/24/2021",count:"0"},{Dates:"05/25/2021",count:"0"},{Dates:"05/26/2021",count:"0"},{Dates:"05/27/2021",count:"0"},{Dates:"05/28/2021",count:"0"},{Dates:"05/29/2021",count:"0"},{Dates:"05/30/2021",count:"0"},{Dates:"05/31/2021",count:"0"},{Dates:"06/01/2021",count:"0"},{Dates:"06/02/2021",count:"0"},{Dates:"06/03/2021",count:"0"},{Dates:"06/04/2021",count:"0"},{Dates:"06/05/2021",count:"0"},{Dates:"06/06/2021",count:"0"},{Dates:"06/07/2021",count:"0"},{Dates:"06/08/2021",count:"0"}];

array2 = [{Dates: "05/25/2021", count: "20"},{Dates: "05/26/2021", count: "0"},{Dates: "05/27/2021", count: "3"},{Dates: "05/28/2021", count: "10"},{Dates: "06/07/2021", count: "0"}];
```

if someone can help me I will appreciate, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a combination of `Array.find` and `Array.forEach`, you can iterate through `array2` and update the matching object in `array1`.

```
array2.forEach(elm => {
  let match = array1.find(x => {
    return x.Dates == elm.Dates
  });
  if(typeof(match) != "undefined")
    match.count = elm.count;
});
```

Full snippet:

```js
array1 = [{"Dates":"05/10/2021",count:"0"},{"Dates":"05/11/2021",count:"0"},{"Dates":"05/12/2021",count:"0"},{"Dates":"05/13/2021",count:"0"},{"Dates":"05/14/2021",count:"0"},{"Dates":"05/15/2021",count:"0"},{"Dates":"05/16/2021",count:"0"},{"Dates":"05/17/2021",count:"0"},{"Dates":"05/18/2021",count:"0"},{"Dates":"05/19/2021",count:"0"},{"Dates":"05/20/2021",count:"0"},{"Dates":"05/21/2021",count:"0"},{"Dates":"05/22/2021",count:"0"},{"Dates":"05/23/2021",count:"0"},{"Dates":"05/24/2021",count:"0"},{"Dates":"05/25/2021",count:"0"},{"Dates":"05/26/2021",count:"0"},{"Dates":"05/27/2021",count:"0"},{"Dates":"05/28/2021",count:"0"},{"Dates":"05/29/2021",count:"0"},{"Dates":"05/30/2021",count:"0"},{"Dates":"05/31/2021",count:"0"},{"Dates":"06/01/2021",count:"0"},{"Dates":"06/02/2021",count:"0"},{"Dates":"06/03/2021",count:"0"},{"Dates":"06/04/2021",count:"0"},{"Dates":"06/05/2021",count:"0"},{"Dates":"06/06/2021",count:"0"},{"Dates":"06/07/2021",count:"0"},{"Dates":"06/08/2021",count:"0"}];

array2 = [{Dates: "05/25/2021", count: "20"},{Dates: "05/26/2021", count: "0"},{Dates: "05/27/2021", count: "3"},{Dates: "05/28/2021", count: "10"},{Dates: "06/07/2021", count: "0"}];

array2.forEach(elm => {
  let match = array1.find(x => {
    return x.Dates == elm.Dates
  });
  if(typeof(match) != "undefined")
    match.count = elm.count;
});

console.log(array1);
```

Comment: The `forEach` extension method would be more appropriate than `map` on `array2`. And I would recommend validating that `array1.find` returns  value before setting the count property. It's not clear if `array2` dates are guaranteed to be in `array1`.

Comment: Fair enough. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you so much men

Answer (score 0):

As a naive approach I would do it like this, is this what you are looking for ?

```
for(let i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
   for(let j = 0; j < array2.length; j++) {
      if(array1[i].Dates == array2[j].Dates)
         array1[i] = array2[j];
   }
}
```

Comment: Yes, both answer help me a lot, thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

A way to only iterate each array once is to create a Map from array2 using Dates as keys , then map the first array using Object.assign().

If the get() in the assign method is undefined (no such date stored) it will just ignore the undefined and return the original values of  array1 object.

This avoids all the additional array looping using methods like find() or nested for loops

```js
const a2Map = new Map(array2.map(e => [e.Dates, e]))

const res = array1.map(e => Object.assign({}, e, a2Map.get(e.Dates)));

console.log(res);
```

```html
<script>
array1 = [{"Dates":"05/10/2021",count:"0"},{"Dates":"05/11/2021",count:"0"},{"Dates":"05/12/2021",count:"0"},{"Dates":"05/13/2021",count:"0"},{"Dates":"05/14/2021",count:"0"},{"Dates":"05/15/2021",count:"0"},{"Dates":"05/16/2021",count:"0"},{"Dates":"05/17/2021",count:"0"},{"Dates":"05/18/2021",count:"0"},{"Dates":"05/19/2021",count:"0"},{"Dates":"05/20/2021",count:"0"},{"Dates":"05/21/2021",count:"0"},{"Dates":"05/22/2021",count:"0"},{"Dates":"05/23/2021",count:"0"},{"Dates":"05/24/2021",count:"0"},{"Dates":"05/25/2021",count:"0"},{"Dates":"05/26/2021",count:"0"},{"Dates":"05/27/2021",count:"0"},{"Dates":"05/28/2021",count:"0"},{"Dates":"05/29/2021",count:"0"},{"Dates":"05/30/2021",count:"0"},{"Dates":"05/31/2021",count:"0"},{"Dates":"06/01/2021",count:"0"},{"Dates":"06/02/2021",count:"0"},{"Dates":"06/03/2021",count:"0"},{"Dates":"06/04/2021",count:"0"},{"Dates":"06/05/2021",count:"0"},{"Dates":"06/06/2021",count:"0"},{"Dates":"06/07/2021",count:"0"},{"Dates":"06/08/2021",count:"0"}];

array2 = [{Dates: "05/25/2021", count: "20"},{Dates: "05/26/2021", count: "0"},{Dates: "05/27/2021", count: "3"},{Dates: "05/28/2021", count: "10"},{Dates: "06/07/2021", count: "0"}];

</script>
```